# Can you please check this proof reguarding a consequence of the closed graph Theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory

In [Engel-Nagel, One parameter semigroups of linear operators] Theorem B.6 p.517 states:

Let $A \colon D(A) \subset X \rightarrow X$ be closed.
$$A \textit{ is bounded  on } D(A)  \iff D(A) \textit{ is a closed subspace.}$$
The proof is missing but the authors say that the Theorem is a reprhasal of the closed graph theorem. I provide a proof, can you please check the correecteness and provide evetually some remarks?

Let $D(A)$ be a closed subspace. Then $(D(A), \| \cdot\|)$ is a Banach space. Since $A$ is closed, by the closed graph Theorem $\implies$ $A$ bounded on $D(A)$.

Conversely let $A$ be bounded  on $D(A)$. Let $\{ x_k\} \subset D(A):$ $x_k \to x \in X$, we show that $x \in D(A) $ $\implies$ $D(A)$ closed.

Indeed $A$ bounded on $D(A)$ $\implies$ $\{Ax_k\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $X$ $\implies $ $Ax_k \to y $ for some $y \in X$. Since $A$ is closed $\implies$ $x \in D(A)$ and $Ax=y$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. :)